# get key basis on value by reading property file in python?

Tags: python, configparser

I have a property file "holder.txt" like this which is in `key=value` format. Here key is `clientId` and value is `hostname`.

```
p10=machineA.abc.host.com
p11=machineB.pqr.host.com
p12=machineC.abc.host.com
p13=machineD.abc.host.com
```

Now I want to read this file in python and get corresponding `clientId` where this python script is running. For example: if python script is running on `machineA.abc.host.com` then it should give me `p10` as `clientId`. Similarly for others.

```
import socket, ConfigParser

hostname=socket.getfqdn()
print(hostname)

# now basis on "hostname" figure out whats the clientId 
# by reading "holder.txt" file
```

Now I have worked with `ConfigParser` but my confusion is how can I get value of key which is `clientId` basis on what hostname it is? Can we do this in python?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong? This can be done inside a simple loop.

Comment: Any reason the config file is stored as `<clientid>=<hostname>` vs. `<hostname>=<clientid>`. If you can store as the latter then you can use `ConfigParser` to directly read it in and then simply `config[<hostname>]` would give you `clientid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to read and store the holder file in memory as a dictionary:

```
mappings = {}
with open('holder.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        mapping = line.split('=')
        mappings[mapping[1].rstrip()] = mapping[0]
```

Then perform a mapping every time you want to get clientId from hostname:

```
import socket, ConfigParser

hostname=socket.getfqdn()
clientId = mappings[hostname]
```

Hope that helps.